# JavaScript Inheritance or How is this Working?

Tags: javascript, oop, knockout.js

I'm trying to achieve a degree of inheritance in JavaScript and here is what I have so far:

```
function Address() {
    this.address1 = ko.observable();
    this.address2 = ko.observable();
    this.country = ko.observableSafe(null, new Country(-1, '', false));
    this.city = ko.observable('');
    this.state = ko.observable();
    this.province = ko.observable('');
    this.zipCode = ko.observable();

    this.countryLookupID = '';
    this.stateLookupID = '';

    ko.computed(function () {
        var newCountry = this.country();
        if (newCountry) {
            this.countryLookupID = newCountry.id.toString();
            if (newCountry.international) {
                this.clearDomestic();
            }
            else {
                this.clearInternational();
            }
        }
        else {
            this.countryLookupID = "";


    }, this);
    ko.computed(function () {
        var newState = this.state();
        if (newState) {
            this.stateLookupID = newState.id.toString();
        }
        else {
            this.stateLookupID = "";
        }
    }, this);
}
Address.prototype.clearDomestic = function () { return true; };
Address.prototype.clearInternational = function () { return true; };

function Company() {
    this.base = Address;
    this.base(this);
    this.legalEntityID = ko.observable(0);
    this.legalEntityName = ko.observable('');
    this.isFemaleOwned = ko.observable(false);
    this.isMinorityOwned = ko.observable(false);
    this.webAddress = ko.observable();

    this.businessPhone = ko.observable();
    this.faxNumber = ko.observable();

    this.locked = ko.observable(false);

}
Company.prototype.constructor = Address;
Company.prototype.clearDomestic = function () {
    this.businessPhone('');
    this.state(null);
    this.zipCode('');
};
Company.prototype.clearInternational = function () {
    this.province('');
};
```

If you are unfamiliar with the Knockout framework, that is OK, as it's probably not pertinent to this discussion. I haven't seen inheritance done exactly like this anywhere that I've looked. As it currently stands, this works exactly how you think it should. When `clearDomestic()` is called, the correct version of the function is called in the inherited class and `this` points to a `Company` object. If I take out the `base` and call to `base(this)`, it breaks.

Can anyone explain why this is working? If this is a bad practice, can someone tell me how to rewrite it so it functions the same? I don't really want to include another library to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

If inside `Address` you invoke `this.clearDomestic()` outside of the `ko.computed`, it tries to call the `clearDomestic()` attached to `Company` but then `this` points to an `Address` object and so `businessPhone` is no longer defined.

**UPDATE 2**

I've moved things around again, and I've settled on this method. It's not ideal, but it's the only way that consistently works.

```
function Address() {
    this.address1 = ko.observable();
    this.address2 = ko.observable();
    this.country = ko.observableSafe(null, new Country(-1, '', false));
    this.city = ko.observable('');
    this.state = ko.observable();
    this.province = ko.observable('');
    this.zipCode = ko.observable();

    this.countryLookupID = '';
    this.stateLookupID = '';
}
Address.prototype.clearDomestic = function () { return true; };
Address.prototype.clearInternational = function () { };

function Company() {
    this.legalEntityID = ko.observable(0);
    this.legalEntityName = ko.observable('');
    this.isFemaleOwned = ko.observable(false);
    this.isMinorityOwned = ko.observable(false);
    this.webAddress = ko.observable();

    this.businessPhone = ko.observable();
    this.faxNumber = ko.observable();

    this.locked = ko.observable(false);

    ko.computed(function () {
        var newCountry = this.country();
        if (newCountry) {
            this.countryLookupID = newCountry.id.toString();
            if (newCountry.international) {
                this.clearDomestic();
            }
            else {
                this.clearInternational();
            }
        }
        else {
            this.countryLookupID = "";
        }

    }, this);
    ko.computed(function () {
        var newState = this.state();
        if (newState) {
            this.stateLookupID = newState.id.toString();
        }
        else {
            this.stateLookupID = "";
        }
    }, this);
}
Company.prototype = new Address;
Company.prototype.clearDomestic = function () {
    // Since we are entering this method via Address, we need a reference back to a real company object with self.
    this.businessPhone('');
    this.state(null);
    this.zipCode('');
};
Company.prototype.clearInternational = function () {
    this.province('');
};
```

I'm going to have to do the logic in the `newstate` and `newcountry` in every object that inherits from `Address` which makes this far from ideal, but until I find a better suggestion, I'm stuck with this.

Comment: That `ko.observable()` function must return a function that does some sort of magic with `this.base`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly, but instead of `this.base(this);`, try calling `this.base.call(this);`? (in the first version of your code).